# Can't get screen resolution through WMIC on fresh Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-10, wmi

Running `wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth` in Windows' command prompt should return my screen's height and width, however when running that command on my fresh Windows 10 install, no values are displayed. This command used to work on my old Windows installation on a previous drive where I had updated from Win7 to Win10. Am I missing something on my fresh Win10 installation that's required for WMIC to get these values?

Comment: Odd issue, Maybe a video driver?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm using the same drivers as my previous windows 10 installation.

Comment: @darryl, do you happen to solve this issue? I am in the same trouble as you did, where on my newly bought Thinkpad X270 machine, running exactly the same command does not get me anything in return. Here goes the screenshot: https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/Ddmo1IQQoPimBhiotjg

Comment: According to the following reference, this new command shall do: `wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution `; from: https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/issues/354